# BigQuery - No cost saving while querying partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I've created a table using a DATE column based partition. The column is evtDate, and I'm not saving any cost when I'm filtering for a dynamic date, like:

```
SELECT evtDate,
machineName,
userName
FROM `xxxx`
where evtDate >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -31 DAY);
```

But GCP uses partitions when a literal value is specified, so I can save costs, like:

```
SELECT evtDate,
machineName,
userName
FROM `xxxx`
where evtDate >= '2020-06-20';
```

Any idea?

Comment: BigQuery does constant folding, so DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL -31 DAY) is evaluated at compile time and is equivalent to DATE '2020-05-30'.

Comment: Ok, I've just realized it was a mistake. Maybe the 24h constant home office working :s. Thank you for your atention

Comment: the second query is only for 10 days, so date_sub(current_date,interval 11 day) or date_add(current_date,interval -11 day) while the first query is a full month, bigquery does the partition pruning in both ways

Answer (score 1):

Forget it! I was wrong.
It works fine the same, using literal value or function.